# A probability distribution for the size of factors relative to the size of a product of 2 numbers?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory

Suppose I have $a$ and $b$. Both are positive prime integers.

$ab=n$

If $a=2$ and $b=3$, then $n=6$ and the factors are 33% and 50% of $n$. $a=5$ and $b=7$ would be 14% and 20%. Given $n$, is there a function/theory that can calculate the probability that the factors of $n$ are within a range of sizes of $n$? For example, the probability that the sizes of the factors of $n$ are between 0% and 50% of $n$ (inclusive) is 1.

If a function doesn't already exist, how should I derive such a function?

Answer (score 0):

When $n=ab$, you know that $\frac 1b$ (or $\frac 1b\cdot 100\%$) of $n$ consists of $a$ and $\frac 1a$ of $n$ consists of $b$.

There is no such this as 'the factors of $n$' when you only take two factors. For example $12=2\cdot 6$ and $12=3\cdot 4$. Which factors should I choose? All integers $n$ do have a unique factorization in prime factors:
$$
12=2^2\cdot 3
$$
But then, you have a product of an arbitrary number of factors, not just two.

Comment: I specially stated that $a$ and $b$ are both prime, so $n$ has exactly 2 factors. I want to know the sizes of the prime factors of all positive integers up to $n$, not just for $n$.